# Calculating statistics across slices of 3D NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Sorry if this has been answered already but I can't find a good solution.

I have a large 3D numpy array with dimensions (1e5, 1e3, 1e3) and I need to calculate a SciPy statistic (Weibull parameters) across each slice of the 1st dimension. A nested for loop would get the job done but obviously not ideal. I've looked at NumPy's apply_along_axis and apply_over_axes functions but they don't give any speed up.

Example code

```
a = np.random((1e5, 1e3, 1e3))
stat = np.empty((1e3, 1e3))

for y in a.shape[1]:
    for z in a.shape[2]:
        stat[y,z] = calculate_statistic(a[:,y,z])
```

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In theory this should work:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((1000, 100, 100))  # fill with your input
stat = np.empty((100, 100))  # result

def calculate_statistic(array1d):  # 1D array as the parameter
    return sum(array1d)  # example function

stat = calculate_statistic(a)

print(stat.shape)  # returns (100, 100)
print(stat)  # returns an array with calculate_statistic(a[:,y,z]) for each y, z
```

However, at least on my machine, I can't allocate 745 GiB of memory for your huge array `a = np.random((int(1e5), int(1e3), int(1e3)))`. Have I misunderstood your question, perhaps?

`apply_over_axes` is useless in this case as it does the same loop calculation as you suggested. A bit better solution would be via @np.vectorize if the above suggestion wouldn't work.